# Does using `tools:overrideLibrary` have any benifits over `minSdkVersion`?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm going to use a library in my project and it shows error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [:library:] ...  Suggestion: use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="test.com.library" to force usage

This prompt lets me know that imported liobrary using higher version (15) than my application min sdk version which is 14.
I want to know if I 
I want to know if I use `tools:overrideLibrary` does it let my application to keep its min SDK version and be installed on phones with API14 or it is not the case? Beside I want to know what is the benefit for using `tools:overrideLibrary` over `minSdkVersion'?

Comment: benefit is that your app will be able to install on 14 SDK devices if you use `tools:overrideLibrary`, but if you will increase your minSDK - the app won't install on 14 SDK devices.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko So how would be possible for library components to run on API14 since they need to run on API15?

Comment: they probably don't need API 15. That is a developer of the library who decided to set it's min SDK to 15. Same way even if you app works OK on API 15, you could set min SDK to 20, and this way restrict installations before API 20. Any way you do it all on your own risk.